# item in horizontal recyclerView do not display properly than in vertical recyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, horizontal-recyclerview

Having a recyclerView which displays items fine when it is in vertical orientation. But when change it to horizontal orientation:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

the item is not displayed correctly.  One sample is the 3rd view (a spinner) in the RelativeLayout having

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

but it is displayed align with parent's left edge, which was supposed to be right side aligned (and it did when in vertical orientation).

[image]

There are views also having issue when with the horizontal recyclerView, such as the textView's width runs out of the parent view's width (which has

```
<TextView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="2"
```

and works fine in vertical recyclerView that confined inside its parent view)

Any special consideration is needed for using horizontal recyclerView?

the interested layout is:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/sponsored_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="false" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/icon"
                android:layout_width="6dp"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sponsored_text"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sponsored_text"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@id/spinner"
                style="@style/Spinner"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:dropDownWidth="216dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that with horizontal recyclerView the measure behaviors differently, that the `match_parent` in the RelativeLayout does not work for the horizontal RecyclerView.  The `widthMeasureSpec` is passed in with 0 in the

```
onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int)
```

Set the width for the relativeLayout in the onMeasure seems working, something like:

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        if (MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
            val windowWidth = context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
            containerView?.let {
                val lp = it.layoutParams
                lp.width = windowWidth
            }
        }
                ... ...

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }
```